# Is there any way I can make this condition work?

Tags: sql, sql-server, conditional-statements

This is my table:

```
DATE        |BRANCH   |DESC
2019-12-25  |ALL      |Christmas Day
2019-12-25  |HO       |Christmas Day
2019-12-25  |TES      |Christmas Day
```

This is my query:

```
DECLARE 
@APPTDATE Datetime = '2019-12-25',
@BRANCHCODE varchar(50) = 'HO'

SELECT *
FROM TABLE_NAME
WHERE CAST([DATE] AS DATE) = CAST(@APPTDATE AS DATE) AND ((BRANCH = @BRANCHCODE) OR (BRANCH != @BRANCHCODE AND BRANCH = 'ALL'))
```

Result:

```
DATE        |BRANCH   |DESC
2019-12-25  |ALL      |Christmas Day
2019-12-25  |HO       |Christmas Day
```

This is my desired result;

If the ([BRANCH] = HO) I need to display only the [DESC] that has a [BRANCH] = "HO";

```
DATE        |BRANCH   |DESC
2019-12-25  |HO       |Christmas Day
```

or if the value of the [BRANCH] is not existing in the table but the specified date is existing in the database;

```
DATE        |BRANCH   |DESC
2019-12-25  |ALL      |Christmas Day
```

EDIT:

So if the BRANCH = HO and the DATE = '2019-12-25' and the table is:

```
DATE        |BRANCH   |DESC
2019-12-25  |ALL      |Christmas Day (1)
2019-12-25  |TES      |Christmas Day (2)
```

Since HO is not existing in the branch list but the date does exist the output should be:

```
DATE        |BRANCH   |DESC
2019-12-25  |ALL      |Christmas Day (1)
```

Because ALL = means any branch as long as the date condition is true.

Is it possible to achieve the result using conditions from my where statement or there is much better ways to execute such result?

Comment: What is your expected final output from those 3 input row?

Comment: So you want all rows in the table where either the branch is _HO_ or the supplied `@BRANCHCODE` does not exist in the table, correct?

Comment: @mkRabbani the first result is wrong the last (2) is my desired output.

Comment: @Abra yes sir but I just need single row result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know you want one row back, you can use `order by` and `top`:

```
SELECT TOP (1) t.*
FROM TABLE_NAME t
WHERE CAST([DATE] AS DATE) = CAST(@APPTDATE AS DATE) AND 
      BRANCH IN ('ALL', @BRANCHCODE) 
ORDER BY (CASE WHEN BRANCHE = @BRANCHCODE THEN 1 ELSE 2 END);
```

This chooses only the desired branch and `'ALL'`.  The order by then orders them with the desired one first, and the `TOP (1)` selects whichever is first.

Comment: I like this approach as it only requires one select query and made to be not so complicated, Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT branch FROM table where branch = @BRANCHCODE)
    BEGIN
        SELECT * FROM table where branch = @branchcode
    END
ELSE
    BEGIN
        SELECT * FROM table WHERE CAST([DATE] AS DATE) = CAST(@APPTDATE AS DATE)
    END
```

These two could be solutions. Haven't tested it on schema.  Hope it helps.

```
SELECT * FROM Table 
WHERE
 1= CASE WHEN branch = @branchCode THEN 1 
 ELSE CASE WHEN CAST([DATE] AS DATE) = CAST(@APPTDATE AS DATE) AND branch != @branchcode THEN 1 ELSE 0 END END
```

Comment: From this line  `1= CASE WHEN branch = @branchCode THEN 1` , what does "1" means sir?

Comment: Its just an indicator that represents this record should be in resultset. or you can consider it as "True"

Comment: the `1` means nothing, basically when the branch code matches && the date matches this collapses into `1=1` otherwise its `1=0`

Comment: Same result from my query sir.

Comment: Try second solution now

Comment: I already tried the 2nd solution sir but the 1st solution doesnt seem right to me because you're executing (3) different select query and it will take so much time if the table has a big data.

Comment: Only 2 statements will get executed at a time.

Answer (score 1):

Use `UNION ALL` for the 2 cases:

```
DECLARE 
@APPTDATE Datetime = '2019-12-25',
@BRANCHCODE varchar(50) = 'HO'

SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME
WHERE [BRANCH] = @BRANCHCODE
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME
WHERE CAST([DATE] AS DATE) = CAST(@APPTDATE AS DATE) AND [BRANCH] = 'ALL'
AND NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 FROM TABLE_NAME
  WHERE [BRANCH] = @BRANCHCODE
)
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=e40c151cdb72d3ce742ee2c11795c420).

Answer (score 0):

You can try this below script-

```
DECLARE @APPTDATE DATETIME= '2019-12-25', 
    @BRANCHCODE VARCHAR(50)= 'HO';

SELECT *
FROM TABLE_NAME
WHERE BRANCH = @BRANCHCODE
OR(
    BRANCH <> @BRANCHCODE
    AND CAST([DATE] AS DATE) = CAST(@APPTDATE AS DATE)
)
```

**Update:**

```
SELECT *
FROM your_table
WHERE BRANCH = @BRANCHCODE
OR(
    BRANCH ='ALL'
    AND CAST([DATE] AS DATE) = CAST(@APPTDATE AS DATE)
)
```

Comment: Same with the result of my existing query sir

Comment: Can you put your expected output together from those 3 input rows? this will help.

Comment: What if HO is also available in the Input table?

Comment: then the row that has a [BRANCH] = HO must be the output result even though the [BRANCH] = ALL is existing in the table.

Comment: Still the same with the result of my existing query sir.

Comment: Please check the fiddle here - https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=ea4a399c2b4fead158a5fa033e29c695